# How to get User Id (Rowid) from SQLite Database and show it in TextView (Android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, authentication, rowid

I made a SQLite Login and Register app. After a successful Login I want the user to see a TextView where he/she sees "Welcome *user_name*" and "Your Id-Number: *user_id*. And by *user_id* I would like to see the RowId.

Here is some code of the **DatabaseHelper**:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserManager.db";

private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";

private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
        + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";

public long getUserId (String email){
    long userId = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {
            COLUMN_USER_ID
    };
    String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { email };

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
            columns,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    userId = cursor.getLong(0);
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    if (cursorCount > 0){
        return userId;
    }
    return userId;
}
```

In the **LoginActivity** I want the get the value of the user name and the user id after clicking in Login. Here is some code:

```
if (databaseHelper.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()
            , textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim())){
        Intent accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, UsersActivity.class);
        accountsIntent.putExtra("NAME", databaseHelper.getUserName(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()));
        Intent idIntent = new Intent(activity, UsersActivity.class);
        String ID = String.valueOf(databaseHelper.getUserId(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()));
        idIntent.putExtra("ID", ID);
        emptyInputEditText();
        startActivity(accountsIntent);
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, getString(R.string.error_valid_email_password), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

And at the end I want it to be displayed in the **UserActivity**:

```
textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    String nameFromIntent = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");
    textViewName.setText("Welcome " + nameFromIntent);

    textViewId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    String idFromIntent = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");
    textViewId.setText("Your Id-Number: " + idFromIntent);
```

However, with the user name everything works just fine but the user id is messed up. It shows me "Your Id-Number: null"

I couldn't find any solution online so I post this here. 
How do I get the user id, which has to be INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT and display it as a string. But to make it even more complicated, I also need the user id as a int/long for further functions (transform to binary code, ...).

Comment: Why you get writable database instead readable database, in getUserId() method?

Comment: @Hetfieldan24 I tried both and both don't work.

Comment: what do you see when you use `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor()` method?

Comment: Check my answer. As I see, you just put your id in wrong intent, which you don't start.

Comment: @pskink I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@5f0694c
I/System.out: 0 {
I/System.out:    user_id=1
I/System.out: }
I/System.out: <<<<<

Comment: so you have `user_id=1` in your first row and 1 should be returned from `getUserId` method

Comment: @pskink Yes. exactly. But the problem was the Intent (as mentioned below) no it returns 1. Thanks.

Comment: ok you set `idIntent` extras but use `accountsIntent` in `startActivity`

Comment: yeah, I changed idIntent to already existing accountsIntent and it worked. I didn't need a new Intent for returning the user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DatabaseHelper is having some bugs and irrelevant code structure.

Replace Your DatabaseHelper like below code.

```
   public class DatabaseHelper  {

    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserManager";

    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";

    private static final String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," 
            + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";


    private final Context context;
    private AppDatabaseHelper appDB;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        appDB = new AppDatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    // Open the database connection.
    public DatabaseHelper open() {
        db = appDB.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public boolean checkIfUserExit(String tableName,String emailId) {
        String where = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL+" LIKE '%"+emailId+"%'";
        Cursor c = db.query(true, tableName, null,
                where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(c.getCount()>0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetUserID(String tableName,String emailId) {
        String where = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL+" LIKE '%"+emailId+"%'";
        Cursor c = db.query(true, tableName, null,
                where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(c.getCount()>0)
            return c.getInt(0);
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public String GetUserUserName(String tableName,String emailId) {
        String where = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL+" LIKE '%"+emailId+"%'";
        Cursor c = db.query(true, tableName, null,
                where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(c.getCount()>0)
            return c.getString(1);
        else
            return null;
    }


    public static class AppDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        AppDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            _db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                    + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");
            // Destroy old database:
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);
            // Recreate new database:
            onCreate(_db);
        }
    }

}
```

You have to call DatabaseHelper in Your Activity like this

```
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
            databaseHelper.open();
```

Get values from your local DB like this

```
if (databaseHelper.checkIfUserExit(databaseHelper.TABLE_USER , textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim())){
        Intent accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, UsersActivity.class);
        accountsIntent.putExtra("NAME",    
 databaseHelper.GetUserUserName(databaseHelper.TABLE_USER ,textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()));
        String ID = String.valueOf(databaseHelper.GetUserID(databaseHelper.TABLE_USER ,textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()));
        accountsIntent.putExtra("ID", ID);
        emptyInputEditText();
        startActivity(accountsIntent);
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, getString(R.string.error_valid_email_password), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I haven't thought about the structure at all. In a video it was shown this way so I just keeped it like that. But anyway, I will change it to improve the App.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Replace

```
cursor.getLong(0);
```

with

```
cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_ID));
```

Upd.:
Also try to remove this:

```
Intent idIntent = new Intent(activity, UsersActivity.class);
```

and replace

```
idIntent.putExtra("ID", ID);
```

with

```
accountIntent.putExtra("ID", ID);
```